The application cannot access the iOS keychain for the application publisher (the TeamId is null)
I am struggling with using MSAL to login to my .net maui app when running it on an iOS simulator. The issue occurs at the PublicClientApplicationBuilder. When I release the app on TestFlight I am able to login successfully but on a simulator I get this error.
Bundle Signing
EntitlementsWIthIosKeychainSecurityGroup
Your assistance will be highly appreciated, we have been struggling with this for quite some time and it makes debugging the app difficult.
Thank you in advance.
I have tried different online suggestions but none of them worked.

Can you share your complete code in the question?
